# iOS 8 Today widget doesn't show up when loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, ios8-extension, notificationcenter

I have created simple timetable widget, but when I try to test it in iOS simulator, it says something like

> Timetable[4012:108619] Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 3965: (null)

And the widget doesn't show up.
Here's my code.

```
#import "TodayViewController.h"
#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>

@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>


@end

@implementation TodayViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableCell"];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 7;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResultFailed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResultNoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResultNewData

        completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 1):

That message appears all the time with today widgets and normally doesn't indicate that anything is actually wrong. Unless you're experiencing some kind of problem that you didn't mention, just ignore it.

The reason your widget is not showing up esthete your code doesn't say how much space you need. You need to set `self.preferredContentSize`. With table views in a widget you usually do something like:

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.preferredContentSize.width, self.objects.count * 44.0);
```

Replace `self.objects` with whatever array you're using for the table data, and replace 44 with your cell height.

Your code uses 7 rows, which is probably too many. See [Issue in Widgets in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28314985/issue-in-widgets-in-landscape-mode/28350142#28350142) for a discussion of why.

Comment: But I see only the name of the widget in iOS simulator.

Comment: I see, you should have mentioned that. Answer updated.

Comment: Strange, but the same thing happens. Can I use custom UITableView height in widgets?

Comment: You can use custom cell height anywhere you use cells. What method did you set the preferred height in?

Comment: I set it in the interface builder.

Comment: No not the cell height. The preferred content size.

Comment: In the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 version:

```
preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: preferredContentSize.width, 
                              height: CGFloat(objects.count) * 44.0)
```